# get_the_post_thumbnail() returning empty string on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, post-thumbnails

I've been brought in to help out with development on an existing plugin, and have run into a strange issue. Not sure if I'm overlooking something obvious here.

The situation: I'm adding a shortcode that will basically spit out a list of posts of a particular custom type, complete with title/link/thumbnail. Standard stuff. The below code is giving me trouble.

```
        if( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            $recipes .= get_the_post_thumbnail();
        }
```

The $recipes variable is returned at the end of the function, to be output with the corresponding shortcode.

**Edit with more info:** The above code is within The Loop, with a custom query limiting retrieved posts to just those of the particular cpt.

All other post info is outputting correctly, but neither `get_the_post_thumbnail()` or `the_post_thumbnail()` return anything. There is a thumbnail attached to these posts in admin, `has_post_thumbnail()` returns true, and even `get_post_thumbnail_id()` works as expected. The thumbnail is definitely there.

I tried changing my query to get regular posts, rather than the custom post type, and thumbnails suddenly worked fine, so it has something to do with the cpt. I've tried making $post global, and even manually adding a post id as a parameter. No effect.

At the moment I'm just using `wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() )` as a workaround but it's driving me crazy not knowing what's wrong.

What ridiculous mistake have I made?

**Things I've tried:**

- Disabling all other plugins, changing to default theme(s)
- Manually entering a valid cpt post ID as the parameter to
  `get_the_post_thumbnail()`
- `global $post;` and using the ID from that

Comment: Try passing in the post ID to `get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'thumbnail');` and specify the image size you want. Check out [these examples](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail#Examples) in the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org).

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned above I've already tried adding in the post id as a parameter with no result. Just double checked it with the size specified too, no change.

Comment: You'll need to post more context. Saying a function doesn't work without any context of how it's used doesn't give us much to go on. Most WordPress functions are not deterministic: calling `the_post_thumbnail` in different places on the page with the same inputs may yield different results, for instance. Depends on global state, etc.

Comment: @Shellbot Double check the post in question indeed does have a featured image set. Then check the results of `has_post_thumbnail($post_id);` is it accurate?

Comment: @MichaelEcklund It's actually all posts of the particular cpt type, rather than one in particular, but yes I've double checked that a thumbnail is set and has_post_thumbnail($post_id) definitely returns true. As I said, even get_post_thumbnail_id() is working so there's definitely a thumbnail there.

Comment: @chrisguitarguy Edited with more info, basically it's inside The Loop. If you need more info, ask away.

Comment: Seems there's something prevent functions work, probably with an hook. Try disable plugins and/or switch theme... It's a very odd issue.

Comment: @G.M. I know, right? Usually disabling plugins and changing to default theme is my rule #1 of debugging so unfortunately that's already been ruled out, but good thinking and I'll add it to the original post to be more thorough.

Comment: seems as there may be a good cause for that, since its 2019 and the behaviour ist still the same

Answer (score 2):

If nothing works, give this a try:

```
$img_attribs = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'thumbnail' ); // returns an array
if( $img_attribs ) {
?> 
<img src="<?php echo $img_attribs[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $img_attribs[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $img_attribs[2]; ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I could not make get_the_post_thumbnail() work. However I found a workaround to display the thumbnail on custom type, just adding the code below.

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'thumbnail' ); ?>
```

Posting in case it may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to get the thumbnail within the loop like home page, category page or any other term page. you have to use - `the_post_thumbnail();`

If you want it in a specific page like single page, you should be using `get_post_thumbnail_id($postId);`

Comment: Just a tip, use backticks( on my keyboard, it is the `~` button) or the `{}` sign above the editor for code, don't use bold lettering :-) Thank you

Comment: Another tip: you can print backticks by using `Alt+96` (numbers are typed on the numeric keyboard, not the one above the letters)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but that solved:

```
$attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
$image = wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'thumbnail');
```

Answer (score 0):

Called from the loop, this worked for me:

```
get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID() );
```

Comment: `get_the_ID()` is redundant. It will use the current post in the loop by default.

Comment: @JacobPeattie that's because calling `get_the_post_thumbnail()` without an argument returns an empty string, as the question so clearly states. Including the "redundant" argument makes it work, for me at least. This solution is one related to the question, not a generic one.

Comment: get_the_ID() gets the id from literally the exact same place as the default argument for get_the_post_thumbnail() does: the global post variable. If one works but not the other then there’s a different more serious issue that should be fixed. Using get_the_ID() like this in that situation would be a hack, not a fix for the issue.